# How to change Junit 4.12 method names by iteration

Tags: java, eclipse, testing, junit

I have extended the FrameworkMethod class like this:

```
private class RepeatedFrameworkMethod extends FrameworkMethod {

    private int number;

    public RepeatedFrameworkMethod(Method method, int i) {
        super(method);
        this.number = i;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        System.out.println(number);
        return String.format("%s[%d]", super.getName(), number);
    }

}
```

When iterating the method, the name remains the same (i.e, number is set once to 0).

```
for (FrameworkMethod testMethod : testMethods) {
        Repeat repeat = testMethod.getAnnotation(Repeat.class);
        if (repeat == null) {
            children.add(testMethod);
        }
        else {
            for (int i = 0; i < repeat.times(); i++) {

                children.add(new RepeatedFrameworkMethod(testMethod.getMethod(), i));

            }
        }
    }
```

This is what I get in Eclipse.

Always 0.
It used to work with Junit 4.11.

any Idea?
Thanks.

Comment: How do you invoke this piece of code and use the results? After adding the obvious variables to your example I got the expected result. A [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be helpful.

Comment: The method is used to repeat each tests n times.   %s[%d]  represents the methodname + the coutner. But the method is invoked only once, therefore the counter remains 0.  With version 4.11 it gets incremented. I guess something has been changed in 4.12. I can´t figure it out.

Comment: Who invokes the method?

Comment: It´s invoked in the getChildren method of the  junit class runner